# Move only "PhoneNumber" from one Column to another Column in the same table

Tags: t-sql

I need a TSQL Code to move only the "PhoneNumber" from one Column to Another Column in the same table, in which the source column has a lot of junk data like (different length of numbers, letters, period, comma) which I don't want to move all those junks.

Comment: Please include some sample data and expected result and also show your attempt

Comment: what is the valid format of your phone numbers ###-###-#### or (###)-###-#####?  use a like to find the valid phone numbers then use and update set to move valid phone numbers to the new column